# switching rows and columns in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like the following:

```
import pandas as pd
datelisttemp = pd.date_range('1/1/2014', periods=3, freq='D')
s = list(datelisttemp)*3
s.sort()
df = pd.DataFrame({'day':s,'stats':['mean','var','std','mean','var','std','mean','var','std'], 's1':[21 ,25 ,27 ,42 ,4 ,74 ,63 ,67, 6],'s2':[34 ,32 ,3, 53 ,75 ,5, 32, 75, 7], 's3':[8 ,82 ,8, 12 ,43 ,12, 99, 99, 95]})
```

I would like to get a dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'sensors':  ['s1','s2','s3','s1','s2','s3','s1','s2','s3'],'day':s,'mean':[21,34,8,42,53,12,  63,32,99],'var':[25,32,82,4,75,43,67,75,99],'std':[27,3,8,74,5,12,74,5,12]})
```

Basically, I need the dataframe to have sensors in rows and stats in columns. Can please someone help me?

Comment: fix your code so it runs without error

Comment: What is the question? If you already are able to create a dummy dataframe that looks like whatever you want, why not use the same code directly? Your first code throws an error.

Comment: This is not the dataframe I have to use (that is larger and definitely more complicated), this is a dummy one I created to make the question here.

Comment: I fixed the errore in the code. thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) with [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html). Last `reset_index`, rename columns and remove column names by [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#changes-to-rename) (new in `pandas` `0.18.0`):

```
print (df.pivot_table(index='day', columns='stats')
         .stack(0)
         .reset_index()
         .rename(columns={'level_1':'sensors'})
         .rename_axis(None, axis=1))

         day sensors  mean  std  var
0 2014-01-01      s1    21   27   25
1 2014-01-01      s2    34    3   32
2 2014-01-01      s3     8    8   82
3 2014-01-02      s1    42   74    4
4 2014-01-02      s2    53    5   75
5 2014-01-02      s3    12   12   43
6 2014-01-03      s1    63    6   67
7 2014-01-03      s2    32    7   75
8 2014-01-03      s3    99   95   99
```